# How to know end of file?

Tags: c, ftp, client, transfer

i'm writing a program to transfer files between a server and a client.I open a file in the server, then i read & send each character until EOF.But the problem is in the client side,
i can read everything, but i can't stop the loop because i can't send the character "EOF.

Is there a way to stop my loop ?

here is the server side code :

```
  while((read(file_fd, &c, 1)) > 0)
   {
     write(connection->socket_client, &c, 1);
   } //works
```

the client side :

```
while ((i = read(connection->socket_server, &c, 1)) > 0)
write(file_fd, &c, 1); //it read everything but never stop
```

Comment: If you would RTFM, you would see that read returns 0 upon EOF. You get EOF when you close the connection.

Comment: You will likely need to send the client some `metadata` with the file length from the sender to know exactly how long the file is. Typically, you will need a well-defined protocol to make this easy i.e. send an `int` [typically 4 bytes] with the file size, then read that many bytes from the server. `EOF` comes on the socket when you tried to read more bytes than are available.

Comment: thx for your answer, but how do you send an integer with write ? i am trying to do write(connection->socket_client, 1111, 4) but i dont know how to fetch it int the client

Comment: Really? `int length = 1111; write(connection->socket_client, &length, 4)` ... but you need to be concerned about byte order if your server and client machines can be different architectures.